# Reference for the Koszul--Malgrange Theorem

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds, sheaf-cohomology

The [Koszul--Malgrange](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Koszul-Malgrange+theorem#KoszulMalgrange58) theorem, roughly, identifies holomorphic vectors bundles over a complex manifold, as those finitely generated projective modules admitting a flat $(0,1)$-connection. The reference given in nlab (in turn taken from Pali)

> Jean-Louis Koszul, Bernard Malgrange, Sur certaine structures fibrées complexes, arch. mat, vol IX, 1958

and an unreferenced contribution from Grothendieck. Does anyone know where to get a copy of this reference. Moreover, what exactly was Grothendieck's contribution?

Comment: The article of Koszul and Malgrange is online here https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02287068 .  It appears they discuss the relation to Grothendieck's ideas in the first few pages, but I would rather leave a translation / summary to an expert.

Comment: The unreferenced contribution from Grothendieck which is cited in Koszul-Malgrange is this expose by Serre in the Seminaire Cartan at ENS http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1953-1954__6__A18_0.pdf and the contribution of Grothendieck that Koszul-Malgrange refer to is simply the well-known Dolbeault-Grothendieck Lemma.